# SharedPreferences always returning true (recycler view)

Tags: java, android-recyclerview, boolean, sharedpreferences, visibility

I'm using sharedpreference to save boolean when clicking on a button, and use it at the start of the activity to set visibilities states. The problem is that it seems to be always returning true, and I don't understand why. If I click on the button and update the visibility, there's no problem, but the fact is that it is always updated, even when I terminate and relauch the app.
Hope you can help.

Here is how I try to retrieve data from Sharedpreferences and try to use it :

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.gridIcon.setImageResource(mimages.get(position));
    holder.ArtisteTexts.setText(artistetext.get(position));
    holder.TitreTexts.setText(titretext.get(position));
    SharedPreferences preferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean artistetextVisibility = preferences.getBoolean("Atextvisibility", false);
    boolean titretextVisibility = preferences.getBoolean("Ttextvisibility", false);
    



    if(position==0)

{
    if (titretextVisibility) {
        holder.Titre.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.TitreTexts.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
   
}
}
```

And here , inside my viewholder when I update it :

```
    button_validation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String ValueTitre = Titre.getText().toString();
            String ValueArtiste = Artiste.getText().toString();


            if (getAdapterPosition() == 0)
            {
                if(ValueTitre.equalsIgnoreCase("Random Access Memories"))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Album validé!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    SharedPreferences preferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    preferences.edit().putBoolean("Ttextvisibility", true).commit();
                    preferences.edit().putBoolean("Tvisibility", false).commit();
                    Titre.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    TitreTexts.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



                }}
```